# What are my (other) options to reduce resource usage on shared hosting?

Tags: wordpress, database-connection, cpu-usage, ram, shared-hosting

I got a message from our shared hosting company (InMotion) informing me our resource usage is too high. We have a WordPress-powered website. To give you an idea of our website, based on Google Analytics, we get 8,343 unique sessions per month. According to our webhost, we used 8660.71 MB of bandwith in January.

One day, InMotion told me there was a spike in CPU usage, and included an excerpt of my access logs which they say indicated "some heavy WordPress Admin activity". They said "We are not exactly sure what this admin user was attempting to accomplish, however this activity does seem to have inflated your account's CPU usage." They included the ID of the item that was uploaded and caused the spike. It was the only file I uploaded that day. It was a 7 kB PNG file; I uploaded it once, deleted it and uploaded it a second time.

I do not understand the complexities of resource usage, so to me, it seems stange that uploading a 7kB twice can bring about spikes and be considered  heavy activities.

When I asked more about the Ressource Usage graph, they replied this : "The numbers are percentages. 100% means you're right at the top of what we consider normal CPU usage on a shared platform. Anything above that is VPS territory. If you zoom in on the graph, you'll see that for the most part you're right at 100%, but you occasionally have spikes over. Going through the logs, your CPU usage is mostly from the Wordpress Dashboard, so disabling the heartbeat feature should reduce your usage the most."

They also told me there was unusual activity to the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

At our hosting company's request, I did the following:

- Disabled WordPress' heartbeat / autosave features
- Installed a caching plugin (WP Fastest Cache)
- Installed P3 Plugin Performance Plugin to see which plugins were using most resources
- I deactivated 2 plugins that were highest in ressource usage : Scroll Back To Top and Simple Page Tester.

But even with these changes, there are still "spikes" in our resource usage and we are receiving warnings. Our host is recommending we either upgrade to VPS hosting or use a CDN service like CloudFlare or MAXCDN.

So my questions are as follow :

- How can I tell what is really causing excessive ressource usage?
- Are there other ways to reduce resource usage caused by WordPress?
- Are CloudFlare or MAXCDN good for this type of situation?

Thank you for taking the time to read. Any help or tips will be appreciated!

Comment: What is your site's URL?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is not at all surprising. If you get 8,343 unique sessions per month and you used 8660.71 MB, then each visitor is taking an average of about 1MB.

Just loading your home page is about 0.525MB, so if people browse your site (plus with admin traffic) it's easy to see how you might use that much.

Yes, a CDN like CloudFlare or MAXCDN would be really good for your situation. Your page is loading a lot of CSS, Javascript and images that could all be moved to a CDN. This would significantly reduce your host bandwidth usage and probably lower your page load time as an additional benefit.